# How can I change the default location of Ubuntu One folder in Ubuntu?

Tags: sync

I am having difficulty in relocating the Ubuntu One folder. I have an SSD+HDD setup and I want to move this folder to the hard disk drive so that will save some write times for my SSD.

Comment: SSD's are very robust, you could write to it non stop for years before it has an effect. In real use it will outlast the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on changing it on 12.04, it might be useful in your case:

[How can I choose a different Ubuntu One default local folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72449/how-can-i-choose-a-different-ubuntu-one-default-local-folder)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the default location of Ubuntu one you can do it as follow:

1. stop ubuntu one syncd:

   u1sdtool -q
2. edit ~/.config/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.cof (append if it doesn't exist):

   [__main__]

   root_dir.default = /path/to/your/directory

   root_dir.parser = home_dir

   root_dir.help = Use the specified directory as the root
3. connect again to syncd:

   u1sdtool -c

-Be sure you have the right permission to write to this new directory

-if you want to keep your old files and folders in Ubuntu One copy them to the new directory before connecting to syncd (3)